# How can I get Recyclerview to show the results from Retrofit?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, retrofit2

I get results from API as indicated in the logcat however the recyclerview isn't displaying them. I am very sure that my Adapter class is olay because I just copied it from the previous code. Am I doing it wrong when it comes to getting items from the json?

```
  Call<List<Post>> call = jsonPlaceHolderApi.getPosts("35", "139", 
  "api_key", 
"weather");

    call.enqueue(new Callback<List<Post>>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<List<Post>> call, Response<List<Post>> 
     response) {
            if (!response.isSuccessful()) {
                Log.i(TAG, "onResponse: getPosts" + response.code());
            } else {

                String posts = response.body().toString();
                Log.i(TAG, "onResponse: getPosts" + response.code());
                try {
                    JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(posts);
                    JSONArray dataArray = obj.getJSONArray("weather");
                    for (int i = 0; i < dataArray.length(); i++) {
                        JSONObject dataobj = dataArray.getJSONObject(i);

                        String main = dataobj.getString("main");
                        String Desc = dataobj.getString("description");

                        Post post = new Post(main, Desc);
                        mpost.add(post);
                          adapter = new Adapter(mpost, MainActivity.this);
                              recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new 
                    LinearLayoutManager(MainActivity.this));
                     recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
                     recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
                      adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                    }
```

My Json look like this

```
  {"coord":{"lon":139,"lat":40},"weather": 
  [{"id":800,"main":"Clear","description":"clear sky",
  "icon":"01d"}],"base":"stations","main": 
  {"temp":299.214,"pressure":1011.11,"humidity":73,        
 "temp_min":299.214,"temp_max":299.214,"sea_level":1011.11,"grnd_level"
 :1011.1 9},"wind":{"speed":3.13,"deg":0.953},"clouds": 
 {"all":0},"dt":1565080981,"sys":{"message":0.007,"country":"JP",        
 "sunrise":1565034375,"sunset":1565085220},"timezone":32400,"id":1850405,
  "name":"Tenno","cod":200}
```

Comment: Does the recyclerview display just one item? Or is there any other problem?

Comment: post your xml here

Comment: @faranjit It doesnt disply anything

Comment: Can you post adapter class too?

Comment: @LakhwinderSingh my Xml is so simple just linear layout with two textviews

Comment: Please check the answer and see if the log prints or not

Comment: @faranjit this https://gist.github.com/ronnixy/09965d8d110d61e483e72d12286234d7

Comment: What is your background color of activity(or fragment) and recycler items(text colors too)?

Comment: First create a Pojo class(Model class), then load the json data on that class as a Arraylist inside the for loop. Outside the for loop call the recyclerview..

Comment: @NavinKumar I have it look closely you will see Post

Answer (score 1):

Try to check if the Log with tag 'I AM HERE' prints or not

```
@Override
public void onResponse(Call<List<Post>> call, Response<List<Post>>
        response) {
    if (response.isSuccessful()) {
        String posts = response.body().toString();
        Log.i(TAG, "onResponse: getPosts" + response.code());
        try {
            JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(posts);
            JSONArray dataArray = obj.getJSONArray("weather");
            for (int i = 0; i < dataArray.length(); i++) {
                JSONObject dataobj = dataArray.getJSONObject(i);
                String main = dataobj.getString("main");
                String Desc = dataobj.getString("description");
                Post post = new Post(main, Desc);
                mpost.add(post);

            }
            // if this prints then problem is in XML or the adapter
            Log.i(TAG, "I AM HERE");
            if (adapter == null) {
                adapter = new Adapter(mpost, MainActivity.this);
                recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new (MainActivity.this));
                recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
            } else {
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

You are creating adapter again and again

BTW if you are using retrofit, use GSON to parse your response than manually parsing it

Comment: Not printing at all

Comment: Then there is an issue in your JSON parsing, print the error in the catch block and see if there is any

Comment: I believe so but in the run section I am getting the data.D/OkHttp: {"coord":{"lon":139,"lat":35},"weather":[{"id":800,"main":"Clear","description":"clear sky","icon":"01n"}],"base":"stations","main":{"temp":301.63,"pressure":1009,"humidity":90,"temp_min":300.37,"temp_max":302.59},"wind":{"speed":2.68,"deg":225,"gust":2.24},"clouds":{"all":0},"dt":1565085097,"sys":{"type":3,"id":2003105,"message":0.0078,"country":"JP","sunrise":1565034993,"sunset":1565084603},"timezone":32400,"id":1851632,"name":"Shuzenji","cod":200}

Comment: What I dont understand is that the log doesnt acknowledge the method being called but in the run I get data back

Comment: data may be printed by the logging interceptor of retrofit, but if data is not parsed appropriately, then code will throw error while parsing

Comment: And if I use Gson I dont get results either but its okay I would stick to volley its working perfectly

Comment: Please see the catch block if it prints anything

Comment: i got it the gson is throwing this error Expected BEGIN_ARRAY but was BEGIN_OBJECT at line 1 column 2 path $

Comment: post your POJO response class

Comment: do you need POJO classes for your response, I can create them if you like

Comment: Hello sorry for the delay. I just figured out the issue. The issue was in the hierarchy of the JSON. I had to watch a couple of tutorials.

Answer (score 0):

```
  try {
                    JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(posts);
                    JSONArray dataArray = obj.getJSONArray("weather");
                    for (int i = 0; i < dataArray.length(); i++) {
                        JSONObject dataobj = dataArray.getJSONObject(i);

                        String main = dataobj.getString("main");
                        String Desc = dataobj.getString("description");

                        Post post = new Post(main, Desc);
                        mpost.add(post);
}
                          adapter = new Adapter(mpost, MainActivity.this);
 LinearLayoutManager linearLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(context);
    linearLayoutManager.setOrientation(LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(linearLayoutManager);
    recyclerView.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());

                     recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
                     recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
                      adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                    }
```

> Initialize  your adapter and call setAdapter() outside for loop